# Why does native browser sort function work slower than quicksort?

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting, quicksort

I implemented quicksort and found that it work faster than native `.sort()` method, [**here is the Performance test**](http://jsperf.com/qsortfasterthennativesort)

Why and how is this happening?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224128

Comment: I'm voting to re-open. The discrepancy needs to be explained with something more than down votes. That being said, the question also really needs to pair down the issue and browsers such that it clearly presents a focused question. The performance is equivalent in IE 10 (which is so say, is about the same as the "slow" Chrome runs).

Comment: OK. I'm voting to re-open. Question could be MUCH better though...

Comment: I think there is an interesting performance phenomena occurring here (in FF and Chrome, IE doesn't care) - but the issue really needs to be *isolated*.

Comment: Could you provide more test cases which includes array of chars, strings, dates, etc. to show the variation of time sorting on different data ?

Comment: As your tests are sorting the same arrays over and over, the comparison is biased towards the algorithm that handles already-sorted arrays better. Btw, in Opera the native sort performs better…

Comment: @Bergi Hmm, the setup isn't done between each run? :-/

Comment: @Bergi Setup done between each run. In each iteration array is generated again.

Comment: @iKBAHT, user2864740: Yeah, and each run consists of a loop of test code executions (check http://jsperf.com/setup). It might not have made a difference for the large cases where the code was only executed once per run, but in general you need to clone the test data for each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that even though the .sort() method is native, it WAY more general than quick sort.

The sort method takes a comparison function. While in the case of quick sort the kind of comparisons are already limited.

The native sort() method is slower to account for more unconventional comparison functions.

Also of note: You should read about underscore.js vs lowdash.

Lowdash is full of methods where a for loop is used instead of a native function for speed.

Update:
I read the comment below and realised my mistake. After some digging, I found the real reason for the slower native performance. The native code is obviously in a lower level language such as C which less "safe" than javascript.

The native function has many checks to ensure there are no errors and things don't break. Javascript code doesn't need as many checks as Javascript as a language tends save you from many such errors anyway.

The answer is still not quite convincing, but .each from lowdash compared to Array.forEach also has a similar result with the low dash implementation being faster. This is because the low dash implementation skips a if (... in ....) check. Little differences such as this can help javascript become faster due to the way Javascript is compiled these days. All function are essentially turned to native code before they run. So the native advantage is minimal.

Comment: How does the quick sort limit the kind of comparison functions? It takes the same generic functions as the native sort method does.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that native function implements quick sort and not stable sort?

Good reads: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort